Refer to the name of a data frame as a character in a nested for loop?
Disclaimer: I've never taken a real class in R (just self-taught through textbook), so sorry if this is a completely backwards way of going about my problem.
I'm running row_t_welch() tests comparing data frames across multiple columns, and then doing this for several data frames, appending the results to an empty data frame, resultsdf. I created a nested for loop for this and it works. BUT the problem is that I want a column of the names of the df being iterated on; it's only returning "x".
The code I have right now:
df1 <- data.frame(
col1 = c(3, 4, 6, 9),
col2 = c(2, 5, 0, 1)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
col1 = c(5, 8, 2, 5),
col2 = c(7, 3, 6, 6)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
col1 = c(4, 5, 8, 2),
col2 = c(4, 5, 3, 1)
)

dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3)

resultsdf <- data.frame(
    dfname = character(),
    pvalue = double()
)

for (x in dflist) {

    for (i in seq_along(x)) {

        itest <- row_t_welch(df1[[i]], x[[i]])

        resultsdf <- add_row(resultsdf,
                            dfname = deparse(substitute(x)),
                            pvalue = itest$pvalue)
    }
}

This is what I'm ending up with:
> resultsdf

  dfname     pvalue
[1]      x 1.00000000
[2]      x 1.00000000
[3]      x 0.79087288
[4]      x 0.04662942
[5]      x 0.69464167
[6]      x 0.40073468

And this is what I want:
> resultsdf

  dfname     pvalue
[1]      df1  1.00000000
[2]      df1  1.00000000
[3]      df2  0.79087288
[4]      df2  0.04662942
[5]      df3  0.69464167
[6]      df3  0.40073468

How might I go about this? Or is all of this completely inefficient and needs to be scrapped?
Thank you!

I would rewrite your loop to use an integer sequence along dflist, as in, for(x in seq_along(dflist)) which will make x take values 1, 2, 3, ..., rather than using for(x in dflist) which will make x take values df[[1]], df[[2]], df[[3]], ....
This way you can easily also access the names of dflist and index them with x. However, this will only work if dflist is named, dflist = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3).
for (x in seq_along(dflist)) {
    for (i in seq_along(dflist[[x]])) {
        itest <- row_t_welch(df1[[i]], dflist[[x]][[i]])

        resultsdf <- add_row(resultsdf,
                            dfname = names(dflist)[x],
                            pvalue = itest$pvalue)
    }
}


Or is all of this completely inefficient and needs to be scrapped?

It's not very efficient and will be slow for large data. But if it runs on whatever data size you are using and you're happy with the execution time, then that's not a problem that needs solving.
A small adjustment that would make things much more efficient is to "pre-allocate" your data to the correct size, and then fill it in in the loop. What's slow about your current approach is that the data gets 1 row bigger each time through the loop, and that can be very inefficient as data outgrows its space in memory and needs to be copied somewhere else. This is untested, but something like this:
n = sum(sapply(dflist, nrow))
resultsdf <- data.frame(
    dfname = character(n),
    pvalue = double(n)
)

row_counter = 1
for (x in dflist) {
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        itest <- row_t_welch(df1[[i]], x[[i]])
        resultsdf[row_counter, ] <- list(
                            dfname = names(dflist)[x],
                            pvalue = itest$pvalue)
        )
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
    }
}


Thanks! I was trying to find a way around using seq_along, but I guess that is the most efficient way. Thank you so much for the efficiency adjustment, too—it was running pretty slow (very large dataset), so this is extremely helpful!

I try almost always to make my loop index over integers. Sometimes it means a little more typing because you need dflist[[x]] instead of just x, but I still find it clear and consistently doing it requires less thought than making a decision every time, and it's more flexible, like here it's easy to use the names.
